# how to get the json array present inside the json object

Tags: json

I have gone thorugh all the previous solved questions related to this same question, but its still giving me the same error,

I want to pull json array "StringValidator" present in given example below

```
{
key: "AppsIds",
collectionValidator: {
key: "AppIds",
value: "bdff7f25d162f433539a3426fc979384,bdff7f25d162f433539a3426fc979384",
delimiter: ",",
minInclusive: 1,
maxInclusive: 20,
stringValidators: [
{
value: "bdff7f25d162f433539a3426fc979384",
key: "AppIds",
regex: "[a-fA-F0-9]{32}",
minLength: 32,
maxLength: 32
},
{
value: "bdff7f25d162f433539a3426fc979384",
key: "AppIds",
regex: "[a-fA-F0-9]{32}",
minLength: 32,
maxLength: 32
}
]
}
}
```

Can any one help me, I'm new with the json

Comment: And when you say "pull json array", are you trying to fetch the "stringValidators" keys in some function ?

Comment: using which language? javascript? php? command line? something else?

Comment: Using java,i tried getJsonArray method JSONARRAY both gives me JSONObject["stringValidators"] not found or JSONarray["stringValidators"] not found

Answer (score 0):

I've surrounded all your keys with double quotes, and the jsonlist.com validator seems to be happy with it. Just visit that site and copy/paste the updated json object below.

In addition, here's a good reference for iterating through JSON key pairs: https://coderwall.com/p/_kakfa/javascript-iterate-through-object-keys-and-values

for example:

```js
var resultJSON = '{"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe","Email":"johndoe@johndoe.com","Phone":"123 dead drive"}';
var data = JSON.parse(resultJSON);

for (var key in data)
{
    //console.log(key + ' : ' + data[key]);
    alert(key + ' --> ' + data[key]);
}
```

```js
{
    "key": "AppsIds",
    "collectionValidator": {
        "key": "AppIds",
        "value": "bdff7f25d162f433539a3426fc979384,bdff7f25d162f433539a3426fc979384",
        "delimiter": ",",
        "minInclusive": 1,
        "maxInclusive": 20,
        "stringValidators": [
            {
                "value": "bdff7f25d162f433539a3426fc979384",
                "key": "AppIds",
                "regex": "[a-fA-F0-9]{32}",
                "minLength": 32,
                "maxLength": 32
            },
            {
                "value": "bdff7f25d162f433539a3426fc979384",
                "key": "AppIds",
                "regex": "[a-fA-F0-9]{32}",
                "minLength": 32,
                "maxLength": 32
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi bob, after your suggestion i have modified the json with double quotes and tired with this code still the json array returns as null

    private static final String filePath = "jsonTestFile.json"; 
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)      jsonParser.parse(reader);
    String Key = (String) jsonObject.get("key");
    System.out.println("The Key: " + Key);

    JSONArray arr= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("stringValidators");

Comment: @SricharanAmarnathHumson - To provide further clarity to your issue, I would suggest that you add more details to your original post. Add the server-side code block to your original post, as well as the errors. This way other folks can provide accurate answers.